# Publish OSGI/Dynamic Plugin to dotCMS Plugins repository

Tags: dotcms

We have developed a OSGI/Dynamic plugin and now we want to publish it to [dotCMS Plugins repository](https://dotcms.com/plugins/). We have explored the [dotCMS Documentation](https://dotcms.com/docs/latest/table-of-contents) but we are unable to find any guideline that explains how third party plugins can be deployed/published to dotCMS Plugins repository. Please share with us a link to such article/tutorial. Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin submissions can be submitted to *codesubmit@dotcms.com*